# Excel VBA Custom Score formula

Tags: excel, vba

Good day, I am trying to create a function in excel that scores a number based on 4 other numbers, I am working on a scorecard for a budget, so I am trying to accomplish the following:

I have a spreadsheet with the following tables
[image]

Now I have 4 columns,(K to N) "Hidden" with the values 157, 143, 128, 114 in them.
I want to create a Formula that takes the Value in A5 and compares them to the other four columns and puts the result in column J. for example, I would put the following formula in J5

> Cell J5= Score(A5,K5,L5,M5,N5)

In order to get the rateing
I have created the following VBA code:

```
Public Function Score(A As Integer, S1 As Integer, S2 As Integer, S3 As Integer, S4 As Integer) As String

    If A < S1 Then
        Score = "1"
    ElseIf S1 + 1 <= A < S2 Then
        Score = "2"
    ElseIf S2 + 1 <= A < S3 Then
        Score = "3"
    ElseIf S3 + 1 <= A < S4 Then
        Score = "4"
    ElseIf S4 + 1 <= A Then
        Score = "5"
    End If

End Function
```

can someone tell me where I am going wrong? 
When I use the Formula I get a `#NUM` error

Comment: You need to assign the return value to `Score`.

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out. Firstly I forgot that I was working with numbers in the millions so `Integer` wasn't working i had to use `long`, I got a result but not the right one, so I decided to try stipulating the the ranges between. Here is my result:
The function stipulates that the lower A is, the better the rating

```
Public Function ScoreDown(A As Long, S1 As Long, S2 As Long, S3 As Long, S4 As Long) As String

 If A > S1 Then
        Score = "1"
    ElseIf S1 >= A And A > S2 Then
            Score = "2"
    ElseIf S21 >= A And A > S3 Then
        Score = "3"
    ElseIf S3 >= A And A > S4 Then
        Score = "4"
    ElseIf S4 >= A Then
        Score = "5"
    End If


End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Good try if it's one of your first efforts.  You have to specify return value of your function - `As String` as the end of the first line.

```
Public Function Score() As String

    Dim iRow As Integer

    iRow = Application.Caller.Row
    A = Range("$A$5")
    S1 = Range("$K" & iRow)
    S2 = Range("$L" & iRow)
    S3 = Range("$M" & iRow)
    S4 = Range("$N" & iRow)

    If A < S1 Then
        Score = "1"
    ElseIf S1 + 1 <= A < S2 Then
        Score = "2"
    ElseIf S2 + 1 <= A < S3 Then
        Score = "3"
    ElseIf S3 + 1 <= A < S4 Then
        Score = "4"
    ElseIf S4 + 1 <= A Then
        Score = "5"
    End If

End Function
```

If you want to yourself select five cells for the funtion, for example `=score(A5,F10, G10, H10, E10)` etc

```
Public Function Score(A As Integer, S1 As Integer, S2 As Integer, S3 As Integer, S4 As Integer) As String

    If A < S1 Then
        Score = "1"
    ElseIf S1 + 1 <= A < S2 Then
        Score = "2"
    ElseIf S2 + 1 <= A < S3 Then
        Score = "3"
    ElseIf S3 + 1 <= A < S4 Then
        Score = "4"
    ElseIf S4 + 1 <= A Then
        Score = "5"
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: Hmm, For some reason it is still not working, I even tried changing the input format.

Comment: Right, sorry, I didn't realise you wanted to read the values directly of the spreadsheet - please try now.  Cheers,

Comment: I used your suggestion, and it works thank you! however I don't want to hard code the ranges for A, S1, S2 ect, as each scorecard per category is different, hence the A As Integer, S1 As Integer.  I want the next guy to use it to be able to select the Range for A and S1 ect.

Comment: Added to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution - in my opinion and if a VBA-free solution is OK - would be to insert one more hidden column before your column K and enter any very large number (just make sure your values in column A will always be lower than that value).

Then enter the following formula in J3:

```
=MATCH(A3,K3:O3,-1)
```